# OOP set method not working properly

Tags: javascript, oop, methods

So I am learning OOP.  The example below doesn't work for me.  And can't figure out why. I've simplified the code to just two variables.  My problem is really at `car1.setOdometer(1000)` This line doesn't work when I try it. Basically this line automatically changes OdometerReading variable. Then when I click button 3 I get and undefined line for 'Miles'.

**js**

```
function Car(Make, Miles) {
    this.make = Make;
    this.odometerReading = Miles;
    this.showInfo = function() {
        alert(this.make + this.odometerReading);
    };
    this.setOdometer = function(newMiles) {
        this.odometerReading = "newMiles";
    };
}

var car1 = new Car("X", 50);
var car2 = new Car("Y", 75);
car1.setOdometerReading(1000);  //this doesn't work for me.
//It winds up changing odometerReading on car1.showInfo() from the onset!
```

**html**

```
<input type="button" value="Car1" onclick="car1.showInfo()">
<input type="button" value="Car2" onclick="car2.showInfo()">
<input type="button" value="Change Car1" onclick="car1.setOdometer()">
```

the book example is like above.  But when I click Car1, the change has automatically happened.  When I click, Change Car1, THEN Car1, I get an undefined message.

But when I make the following changes, the code works.
edit 'this.setOdometer' here:

```
this.setOdometer=function(newMiles){this.odometerReading=1000;}
```

delete

```
car1.setOdometerReading(1000);
```

Am I missing something, or is the tutorial book just wrong?

Comment: Is this code missing the closing bracket starting at `function Cars(Make, Miles){`? Also the function has the wrong name, it should be `Car` instead of `Cars`.

Comment: setOdometerReading() is not defined anywhere.

Comment: Have you copy pasted this from somewhere or written it by hand? There are mistyped function names and other small mistakes. Double-check everything. Use your [browser's dev tools](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820).

Comment: use your browser console...this code should be throwing several errors. You should have at least seen those errors before asking here ... and included them in the question. Either that or be more careful copying code to questions if that is not the case

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt no that's on me.  I'm basically wrote it out on Sublime.  The code there has the proper bracketing

Comment: Well I think all you're doing wrong is calling the wrong function (`setOdometerReading` but should be `setOdometer `). Also it's weird that the function doesn't make use of the parameter `newMiles` but instead sets it to a static string (`this.odometerReading = "newMiles";`).

Comment: @PrashantPalikhe that's from the tutorial book.  i'm doing the best I can.  my rep just got obliterated.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's reference code for a working implementation. Correctly sets `odometerReading` for `car1`. The errors were just all because of typos, I guess.

```
<head>
<script>
function Car(Make, Miles){
    this.make = Make;
    this.odometerReading = Miles;

    this.showInfo = function() {
        alert(this.make + " " + this.odometerReading);
    }

    this.setOdometer = function(newMiles) {
        this.odometerReading = newMiles;
    }
}
var car1 = new Car("X", 50);
var car2 = new Car("Y", 75);
car1.setOdometer(1000);  //now it has the right function name and actually uses the parameter.
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="Car1" onclick="car1.showInfo()">
<input type="button" value="Car2" onclick="car2.showInfo()">
<input type="button" value="Change Car1" onclick="car1.setOdometer('something Else')">
</body>
```

Comment: the thing is 50 never get called for car1.  it should be make x and miles 50 and use the parameter so that it doesn't need to be used on the onclick event.

Comment: `odometerReading = 50` is immediatly overwritten by calling `setOdometer(1000)`. If you leave that line out, it will have a value of `50`. I had the `setOdometer()` make use of the parameter because it is literally a setter function, setting it to a static string didn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

I see class Cars and new objects of type Car.

Comment: it should be car.  sorry